# How to use a loop to instantiate objects?

Tags: python, python-2.7

When using a for loop to iterate through iterations you want to initiate as objects, how do you do so within a class. How do you use a loop to generate objects?

Because `self._i`, disallows the use of the placeholder variable. Must I manually type out object instances? Is there a way to generate object instance names with string manipulation and then change the data type of the string?

Here is a code example:

```
self._strip=    [self._led1,self._led2,self._led3,self._led4,self._led5,self._led6,self._led7]
    for i in self._strip:
```

See how i have manually typed out elements of the list, and they are not string objects. how do i generate a list full of object handles or variable declarations.

Comment: What is your use case? Why don't you use another data structure like a list instead of separate variables?

Comment: ok, but how do i generate a list full of object handles instead of strings?

Comment: Why do you have properties like _led1, _led2... in the first place?

Comment: because this is a snippet of a class in which i initialise a strip of leds,

Answer (score 0):

Your question is far from being clear - but assuming your object does have the "_led1" to "_ledn" properties, and you want to retrieve each of them, you can do:

```
for i in range(1, n):
    led = getattr(self, "_led{}".format(i))
    . . .
```

`gettattr` retrieves attributes of objects given a string - and the string can be manipulated with format, concatenation, etc...

Comment: many thanks friend, yes i think my question was very poorly worded, that is a reflection on my poor understanding of what i am doing i suppose, i think i may need to just go and watch a lot more tutorials on youtube.